# Azure AKS - Error creating load balancer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I'm following the tutorial to run a containerized application on Azure AKS on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application but my deployment failes to create a load balancer for my service:

```
Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer        3m (x12 over 33m)  service-controller  
Ensuring load balancer
Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  3m (x12 over 33m)  service-controller  
Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to ensure load balancer f 
for service default/azure-vote-front: azure.BearerAuthorize
#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/load
Balancers/kubernetes-internal?api-version=2017-03-01: StatusCode=0 -- 
Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'
```

When running kubectl get service myservice --watch the external ip just stays in status pending.
What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the AKS cluster with the service principal that lacks permissions to create\manage resources for the cluster. you need to recreate the cluster with the proper service principal (much easier than fixing).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. I ran into the same issue when deploying an application based on an image from azure container registry. Adding the service principal to the resource group of the ACR solved that as well.

Comment: Just Complementing how to do it... The documentation says that you need:
"The service principal used ... needs at least Network Contributor ... or if custom Role : Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action
Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/read"
Therefore you can run: 
`az role assignment create --assignee $appId --scope $scopegroup --role "Network Contributor"
`
being $scopegroup the groupid where your loadbalancer is deployed. I believe you can also specify the LB ID.
[aks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal)